# Asus TF700T Does not prompt for forgot password

Tags: lock-screens, asus-eee-pad-transformer, locked-out, pattern-lock

I've read through the many posts about being locked out of a tablet/phone, but haven't found one where the forgot password / forgot pattern option is missing.

I haven't used my Asus TF700T tablet for a couple of months and have forgotten the pattern unlock. After attempting a few times, I get the standard "you have incorrectly drawn your unlock pattern xx times". However, there are never any on-screen options for "forgot password" or "forgot pattern" or similar.

I've tried Google's device manager site: https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager however, I did not set up this tablet to be remotely locked (shame, because apparently I set up my phone to use the service).

I've also gone to the Asus device tracker site: http://devicetracker.asus.com/ and entered the serial number, but the site fails with a "command failed" response. (fwiw, I verified the serial number).

**TLDR;**
In summary, I have tried the pattern unlock 65+ times and still do not get a forgot password or similar prompt. And the tablet is associated with a Google account and the Google play store.

Short of performing a factory reset, is there a way to force the "forgot password" prompt to login to the tablet?

Comment: Well, I feel quite silly. I tried a few more times and found the "forgot password"; my screen's background was nearly the same color of the text and it was all but hidden. Feel free to close this question as operator failure.

Comment: You should post an answer to your question and accept it. It might help a future visitor who makes the same mistake!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to recall my lock pattern a few more times, I noticed I had previously overlooked the "forgot password" text that was an inch or two below the lock pattern. The text blended in with my tablet's background and was barely visible. Chalk this one up to a clear case of operator failure.